# Find and replace text in a file in python

Tags: python, string

The replace function in fileInput doesn't identify the concatenated strings in a file.

It works well if I hard code.

```
DragInitialX = 1
DragForceX = 1000
for line in f:
    findText = 'value           uniform ('+str(DragInitialX)+' 0 0);'
    replaceText = 'value           uniform ('+str(DragForceX)+' 0 0);'
    print(line.replace(findText, replaceText))
```

Comment: Hi perhaps the string isn't present? Maybe inspect the text with a hex editor.

Comment: Make sure you're using the right kind of whitespace: tabs versus spaces. Maybe you should use `re.sub()` instead.

Comment: re.sub() does't help.

Comment: Can you show the code for replace in fileInput and also a sample string from the file please? my first thoughts are to use `exec` but I'm not sure what the input from the file is.

Comment: I have imported fileInput to my code.  So I dont know the code for replace.                     My sample text file looks like below:                                                
subBoundary
    {
        type            fixedValue;
        value           uniform (1 0 0);
    }

Comment: Can you test if the line content is recognized correctly? Maybe use `print(findText in line)` to check if the text actually matches the line.

Comment: Also, `str.replace()` returns a new string and it seems you only print this out, you don't store it anywhere. Is that intended like that?

Comment: yes, it identifies the text given in quotes correctly, when hard coded.  and yes, I dont want the old text.  I just want the findtext to be replaced by replaceText in the same file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating python version solved this issue. Thanks for your help